# Sort MySQL in Human

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

here's the code:

```
$sql_namesResult = mysql_query("SELECT name  FROM `scrimaprovedlist` ORDER BY `scrimaprovedlist`.`eorank`");
```

eo rank is a NUMERICAL value for a rank (general, colonel, ect).

The problem is, when i set myself for 1, i am the top, but comes rank 10, instead of rank 2. how do i edit this to make it show in order:

```
1
2
3
10
20
30
```

I'm currently using "rank" instead of "eorank" because it is easier. but the problem is i have to manually edit the ranks over and over again so that they show in the correct order. Any ideas?

Viewable at http://www.thexcrew.com/modules.php?name=Roster

Comment: Are those fields ints, or strings? They need to be ints.

Comment: @silky, post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
ORDER BY CAST(scrimaprovedlist.eorank AS INTEGER)
```

Your ranks are strings instead of integers so they will be sorted as a string unless you cast or convert them to integers which I've done above

Comment: I'd suggest updating the underlying table to make them INTEGER type, assuming the field only holds numbers.

Answer (score 0):

figured out a way, i changed my Numerical value to an alphabetical value. using only 17 ranks, i am able to substitute #'s for letters. thanks for the help anyway :)